# Applying a vector of functions on vectors

Tags: functions, soft-question, notation

Is there an adequate mathematical representation (operator $\star$) to apply a vector of functions to another vector of values, element by element? 
Something like the following:

$$  \left[ f_1, \ldots, f_i, \ldots  f_n \right ] \star \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      x_1\\
      \vdots\\
      x_i \\
      \vdots\\
      x_n
    \end{array} 
\right] = \left[ f_1(x_1), \ldots, f_i(x_i), \ldots  f_n(x_n) \right ]$$

with $f_i:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\forall i \in [1,n]$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is effectivelly simply a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$.

There is plenty of theory covering such mappings, especially the fields of multivariate calculus and linear algebra.